# create a sym link from a folder content to another directory

Tags: server, 20.04, symbolic-link, apache2.4

I have a Ubuntu server running in a virtualized environment for my web development activities. The host OS is sharing with Ubuntu a folder with this path:

```
/media/psf/Sites
```

and this folder `Sites` contains single files and other folders (i.e. `index.php, folder1, folder2`) and so on.

I run `apache` on the ubuntu box and my document root is `/var/www/html`
I want to create a sym link from `/media/psf/sites` to `/var/www/html` so that inside `/var/www/html` I find `index.php, folder1,folder2` and so on. I tried to do it but ended up with `/var/www/html/Sites`.

My goal is that if I add something in Sites (a new file or folder) the same is reflected in `/var/www/html` without the need to add a new symlink.

Is it possible? Or do I need to keep `/var/www/html/Sites` for this? Alternatively, is it possible to move the document root directly to /media/psf/Sites (that is a mounted folder)?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the host operating system? What is the path to the shared folder in the virtual machine?

Comment: The host is osX virtualized with parallels and the path is /media/psf/Sites in the virtual machine. Parallels puts in /media/psf/ all the folders you want to share between host and guest and there are no chances to change this setting

Comment: Add this information to your post: use "edit". Then it is simple. Replace `/var/www/html` by a symbolic link to `/media/psf/Sites`. One caveat could be that Apache may require that the `/var/www/html` location supports linux permissions.